# Unable to move file from one s3 bucket to another using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to move a file from one s3 bucket to another, I am using boto3 copy function but I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

This is how I am calling the copy function:

```
 copy_source = {"Bucket": f'{exampleBucket1}', "Key": f'{myFile}'}
 connection.meta.client.copy(copy_source, Bucket=f'{exampleBucket2}', Key=f'{myFile}')
 #connection.Object(f'{exampleBucket1}', f'{myFile}').delete()
```

can someone plz tell me where am I making mistake?

Comment: Can you make sure `myFile` exists in `exampleBucket1`?

Comment: Yes, file is there

Comment: I really, really think it is saying that the file doesn't exist in that bucket!

Comment: File is there, I can copy and remove files from AWS cmd but cannot do using Python Script